# Rails model.valid? return falsely returning true

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The model validation fail with_context

**model**

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  with_options on: :basic_info_steps do
    validates :name, presence: true
  end
end
```

**controller**

```
def create
  @user = current_user
  @course = Course.new(session[:course_attributes])
  @course.assign_attributes(course_params)
  if @course.valid?(context: :basic_info_steps)
    session[:course_attributes].merge!(@course.attributes)
    redirect_to [:new, :courses, :details_info_steps]
  else
    render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

> > @course = Course.new(session[:course_attributes])
> > => #<Course id: nil, name: "", actived: true......

Name is empty but

> > @course.valid?(context: :basic_info_steps)
> > => true

> > @course.save(context: :basic_info_steps)
> > => false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

surprisingly the syntax is different for setting the context for the `valid?` and `save` methods*, so this works:

```rb
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true, on: :basic_info_steps
end


course = Course.new(name: "")

course.valid?(:basic_info_steps) #=> false
course.save(context: :basic_info_steps) #=> false
#but:
course.valid?(context: :basic_info_steps) #=> true, weird huh?
```

* see [rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on)

Comment: oh yes, very strange

Comment: Even stranger still is that `with_options on: {context: :basic_info_steps}` will work for `valid?(context: :basic_info_steps)` but won't work for `save` with the same arguments and you can't use it as `with_options on: [:basic_info_steps,{context: :basic_info_steps}]` (`valid?` will pass and `save` will fail)